# I removed snap on my kubuntu installation. What will happen if ii upgrade to 22.10?

Tags: kubuntu, do-release-upgrade

I removed snap on my kubuntu installation. What will happen if i upgrade to 22.10 or later? Will i break my install if i hold the package back?

Answer (score 1):

> I removed snap

and

> Will i break my install if i hold the package back?

are 2 different things. Removing a package removes it and the system will skip updating that package. [Holding](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/man8/apt-mark.8.html) (/[pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto)) a package fixates it to a specific version (ie. using `apt-mark hold`).

> What will happen if i upgrade to 22.10 or later?

"Holding" a package prevents it from updating; during an upgrade you will get a "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading" and the upgrade will halt. If that is not the case the system will disable 3rd party sources and then update all the software that is installed.

Comment: I thought it would automatically reinstall snapd un upgrade and i don't want that.